# MongoDB transforming document by moving a child attribute up one level

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents.

```
{ "id" : 2, "color" : { "description" : "red" } }
{ "id" : 2, "color" : { "description" : "blue" } }
{ "id" : 2, "color" : { "description" : "purple" } }
{ "id" : 3, "color" : { "description" : "red" } }
{ "id" : 3, "color" : { "description" : "orange" } }
```

But I want to move the color value up one level like this:

```
{ "id" : 2, "color" : "red" } 
{ "id" : 2, "color" : "blue" } 
{ "id" : 2, "color" : "purple" } 
{ "id" : 3, "color" : "red" } 
{ "id" : 3, "color" : "orange" }
```

Is there any way to do this as part of an aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you wish to insert the document or just return the result the result as part of aggregation query? If later, using aggregation you can do it like below -

```
> db.coll1.aggregate([{$project:{id:'$id','color':'$color.description'}}])
```

and the result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a4486946c4238ae80280941"), "id" : 2, "color" : "red" }
```

Please let me know if this was what you were looking for?